# Adding element to Webbrowser

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I have a table with id="table1" loaded in my webbrowser webbSPPagina. I need to add an extra row. With this code I can add the row to the table element but it isnt shown on the webbrowser. Do i need to change something to my webbrowser?

```
HtmlElement element = webbSPPagina.Document.GetElementById("table1");
HtmlElement mTBody = element.FirstChild;
HtmlElement mTR = webbSPPagina.Document.CreateElement("TR");
HtmlElement mTD1 = webbSPPagina.Document.CreateElement("TD");
HtmlElement mTD2 = webbSPPagina.Document.CreateElement("TD");
HtmlElement mTD3 = webbSPPagina.Document.CreateElement("TD");

mTD1.Style = "VERTICAL-ALIGN: top";
mTD2.Style = "VERTICAL-ALIGN: top";
mTD3.Style = "VERTICAL-ALIGN: top";
mTD1.SetAttribute("class", "ms-rtetablecells");
mTD2.SetAttribute("class", "ms-rtetablecells");
mTD3.SetAttribute("class", "ms-rtetablecells");
mTD1.InnerText = "Teamviewer Id";
mTD2.SetAttribute("id", "TeamviewerId");
mTD3.SetAttribute("id", "TeamviewerIdExtra");

mTR.AppendChild(mTD1);
mTR.AppendChild(mTD2);
mTR.AppendChild(mTD3);
mTBody.AppendChild(mTR);
```

Comment: You're only copying the docunent body and changing that copy - you still need to set the document to the edited copy.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, it is working for me if I do it in the following way

```
 //Add table in the form load event
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     webbSPPagina.DocumentText = "<table id='table1'><tr><td>hello</td></tr></table>";
 }

 //Added your code in a button click event
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   HtmlElement element = webbSPPagina.Document.GetElementById("table1");
   HtmlElement mTBody = element.FirstChild;
   HtmlElement mTR = webbSPPagina.Document.CreateElement("tr");
   HtmlElement mTD1 = webbSPPagina.Document.CreateElement("td");
   HtmlElement mTD2 = webbSPPagina.Document.CreateElement("td");
   HtmlElement mTD3 = webbSPPagina.Document.CreateElement("td");

   mTD1.Style = "VERTICAL-ALIGN: top";
   mTD2.Style = "VERTICAL-ALIGN: top";
   mTD3.Style = "VERTICAL-ALIGN: top";
   mTD1.SetAttribute("class", "ms-rtetablecells");
   mTD2.SetAttribute("class", "ms-rtetablecells");
   mTD3.SetAttribute("class", "ms-rtetablecells");
   mTD1.InnerText = "Teamviewer Id";
   mTD2.SetAttribute("id", "TeamviewerId");
   mTD3.SetAttribute("id", "TeamviewerIdExtra");

   mTR.AppendChild(mTD1);
   mTR.AppendChild(mTD2);
   mTR.AppendChild(mTD3);
   mTBody.AppendChild(mTR);

  }
```

Comment: the problem with this solution is that the webbrowser loose al elements except table1